# ComboBox и дополнительная информация

Tags: c#, winforms

Я заполняю ComboBox из List, который содержит ID и Name.

Можно ли сделать так, что бы ComboBox по определенному индексу возвращал не только Name, но и реальный ID ?

Answer (score 1):

Да, можно, например так:

```
var comboBox = (ComboBox)sender;
int selectedValue = Convert.ToInt32(comboBox.SelectedValue);
string selectedText = comboBox.SelectedItem.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var youclass =  cbxObjects.SelectedItem as YouClass;

if(youclass != null)
   id = youclass.Id;
```